# Copying a pointer, change what the copy is pointing to without changing original?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-address

Is it possible to copy a pointer, and then change the value it's pointing to without changing what the original pointer is pointing to?

For example, say I had the following:

```
int *i;
auto j = i;

*j = new_val;
```

This would change the value stored at the address `i` is pointing to because both `i` and `j` are pointing to the same memory address, which I do not want.

Since this example case is so simple, I could simply just create a new `int *j` without copying over `i`. But in more complicated cases, such as a linked list, I would not want to recreate a linked list.

So I guess my question boils down to if it is possible to copy a pointer, and have the copy point to a different address but maintain the structural integrity of the original pointer?

Comment: You should use `unique_ptr` which won't let you do `auto j = i;`. But then you want a clonee too. I guess you could make a class of your own - perhaps a generic class - and then overload the assignment operator..

Comment: You’ll need to somehow clone the object. There’s nothing in the language itself that does it for you. The objects of course may have copy constructors which may help here, but you have to write the code to use it to clone the object anyway. For a thing like a linked list it’s not trivial how that would work.

Comment: @sjsam I have never used smart pointers before (something that I want to get more familiar with in the near future). I just briefly looked up `unique_ptr`, and yes, it would not let you make a copy of `i`. But a `unique_ptr` wouldn't help me achieve what I want in this case right? You were just mentioning that to note that I can not do `auto j = i` if `i` was a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ah I see. So it looks like that I have to clone the structure, and there isn't some really simply way to copy it over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First some clarification. Pointer is a standalone **variable** that holds a memory address. Nothing more, nothing less. The type of the poitner means that you, the programmer, told the compiler what is stored at that address so that you can retrieve the value stored at that address - this is called dereferencing.

Now with that in mind you should be able to work out what you want to do yourself but let us walk through the process and we will use smart pointers because they help us manage the memory:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> i = std::make_unique<int>(10); 
//Here we created a variable on the heap and gave it a value 10,
//the address of it is stored in **i**

std::unique_ptr<int> j = std::make_unique<int>(*i);
//Here we created a variable on the heap nad gave it a value
//stored at the address in **i**. Notice the dereferencing
//that means we want to copy the value pointed to,
//not the pointer itself.
```

Now without smart pointers if that makes more sense for you:

```
int *i = new int(10);
int *j = new int(*i);
delete i;
delete j;
```

This does the same thing but you need to manage the memory yourself and it will leak when an exception is thrown for example.

Now this will work for all types that are either trivial like an `int` in the example or those that have the copy constructor defined. Compiler will typically generated one for your types automatically unless it cannot do that for some reason in which case you will have to provide it yourself:

See here for more details: [Copy Constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

EDIT: Some very good explanation of pointers including demonstration of how to do what you want to do: [C++ Pointers by TheCherno](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTxHyVn0ODg)

Comment: This would work for a linked list? Say I am given a pointer to the head of the linked list (not necessarily a smart pointer, and not necessarily allocated on the heap), `linked_list_node *head`. If I do something like `linked_list_node *copy_head = new linked_list_head(*head)` or even *copy_head = &(*head)` , this would copy over the structure?

Comment: @David You need to store it somewhere. As I mentioned pointer is just an address, you need it to point to something. So you can either assign it to a stack variable like this `linked_list_node copy_head = *head;` or allocate it on the heap like this `linked_list_node *copy_head = new linked_list_node(*head);` or better yet use the smart pointer `std::unique_ptr<linked_list_node> copy_head = std::make_unique<linked_list_node>(*head);`.

Comment: I think I understand, how would you do this on the stack? You wouldn't be able to use smart pointers, but would there be a way to achieve what I want with raw pointers?

Comment: @David The first suggestion `linked_list_node copy_head = *head;`

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that ! Thanks. So essentially, the stack case, `copy_head` is no longer a pointer, but in the heap case, `copy_head` is still a pointer.

Comment: @David No problem. Just note that if you use the version I used in my second comment you will also need to have copy assignment operator. It is also automatically generated but if you happen to need to provide one yourself it would have this signature: `linked_list_node &operator=(const linked_list_node &other);`